# Getting "an error occurred while sending the request" while trying to create an application registration on Azure programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-webapps

I have a use case for a project where I need to automate the creation of Application Registration on Azure programmatically.

I have been using this [sample.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph) for doing so.

I am also following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#response) from microsoft on creating an application.

[image]

I have done the same in my code snippet as shown in the image below and also added the functionality to add a password to the created Application.

[image]

This process used to work before where in the Application used to get registered and the flow was as expected.

However now when I try running this request, I get an error saying "Error occurred while sending the request". There does not seem to be any documentation related to error codes related to this.

Can you help me find the relevant material or changes that have been made my microsoft on graph client that may be causing this?

**Update**

As per comments I found the IDs of the needed API Permissions using Powershell.
I added them to my code as well as follows

[image]

The Permissions added are Application.ReadWrite.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy respectively as Type role. I still get the same error.

The inner exception is as follows:

[image]

Comment: May I know if there is any other details of the error message. It should be some more error details after `Error occurred while sending the request` when you run the code. Could you please share the details ?

Comment: Hi Hury. No that is the only line that comes up when I catch that Exception.
However I just noticed something that I may have missed. Can you let me know if that can be the cause?

User.Read, ServiceHealth.Read, ActivityFeed.Read are the api permissions that I have added into the process while creating the application. However I see that on the documentation, one of these permissions is required
Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy.

I do not have these permissions set in my code.

Comment: Could you please use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as the `scope` in your code and add the `Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission in Delegated type to your registered app "API permissions" tab

Comment: Sorry, just need to add one of permissions of `Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All` to "API permissions" tab. Do not need all of them.

Comment: Hi Hury. Yes I am trying the same right now. Do you know how I can get the GUID for those Api permissions?

Comment: You can request this url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'` to get all of the permissions and their id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize from the comments:

The problem was caused by permissions. We should add the required permissions(add at least one of the two permissions `Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All` in Delegated type) to the registered app "API permissions" tab and then just use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as `scope` in code.

By the way, if want to add the permissions by their id, we can get the permissions and ids by request this url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'`

================================**Update**===========================

First you need to have a registered app in your Azure AD. Here I have an app named "huryGetToken4". If you do not have the app, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) to register the app. Go to your registered app and click "API permissions" tab. Add the permissions which are required.
[image]

[image]

Please do not forget do "Grand admin consent for xxx" after add the permissions.

Then click "Certificates & secrets" tab and new a client secret. Copy the secret to your notepad.
[image]

Then we can develop the code, below is my code for your reference:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("clientId")
            .WithTenantId("tenantId")
            .WithClientSecret("clientSecret")
            .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var application = new Application
            {
                DisplayName = "huryNewApp1"
            };

            await graphClient.Applications.Request().AddAsync(application);
        }
    }
}
```

For the `clientId` and `tenantId` in my code, you can find them on the "Overview" page of your registered app.
[image]

After running the code, the new app will be created in Azure AD.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hury. Sorry for the late response but it still doesnt seem to be working. I added in the api permissions to my code and tested it out but it still gives me the same error. I have enclosed a screenshot of code and the inner exception in the question again as an update.

Comment: @Saurab Could you please share a screenshot of the "API permissions" tab page of your registered app ?

Comment: @Saurab And may I know which flow did you use to do authorization in your code ?

Comment: The process of this code to first create an application which would have the api permissions in it. The application itself is not getting created for me to search for permissions tab. 
As for your next question I am not really sure. Is this what you are asking for?
"ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(application);"

Comment: This is the Inner Exception Stack Trace "at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.ClientCredentialProvider.<AuthenticateRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext()"

Comment: @Saurab No, do not add the permissions to the app which you want to created. You should add the permissions to the registered app which you use its client id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229712/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-saurab).

Comment: Hi @Saurab May I know if your problem was solved ? If it was solved, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Saurab Any update for this post ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @Hury Shen. Extremely sorry for the delayed response. Yes your solution helped me resolve it. I understood the issue I was creating. Thanks for the help. I have added your response as a solution.